# Add tooltips with image in Wordpress Menu?

Tags: menus, images, sub-menu, tooltip

I want to add tooltips with image modal inside my menu dropdown.
See this link: [My site](http://www.ad-via.com/led/)

When on the dropdown menu, when we hover on the the product item, I want a tooltips with image to it.

How could I achieve this whether with plugin or something elses?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Plugins recommendations are off-topic here, so maybe you can show us what you have tried?

Comment: I need to find the way to do it and sorry my site using 3rd party plugin. But, is there anyways that could achieve that function in normal Wordpress menu?

Comment: Not by default, please read the http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask , your question will probably be closed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know I can't ask this kind of question though!